# How to receive other datatables columns

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatables

A question regarding AJAX and Laravel. I'm using jquery `datatables` plugin. Right now everything is working fine and my data is returned as expected please. This is my columns section

```
        columns: [
        {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
        {data: 'slug', name: 'slug'},
        {data: 'title',
            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return '<a href="/super/artikels/">'+data+'</a>'
            }, name: 'title'  },
        { data: 'body' ,  name: 'body'  },
        { data: 'author' ,  name: 'author'},
        { data: 'created_at',  name: 'created_at' },
    ]
```

My question is how do I add the slug to the url of the title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using `datatables` jquery plugin and you can use row parameter for access the other columns..

```
render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return '<a href="/super/artikels/'+row.slug+'">'+data+'</a>'
            }, name: 'title'  },
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Appreciate it